# Having trouble with images in my lightbox opening more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I have a lightbox set up with about 40 images. When I first click on it, the image opens and works. I can close it and click on it again and the box will pop up, but no image. If I click on another image, it works. And then I can go back to the original image and click and it will work again. But I can't open it twice in a row. If it helps you answer this, here is my jQuery code:

function light_on() {
                $('#dark #light').stop(true).height(0);

```
            var theSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
            $('#dark #light .target img').attr('src',theSrc);

            $('#dark #light .target img')
                .stop(true)
                .css({'opacity':'0'})
                .load(afterLoad);

            var height = $('#dark #light .target img').load(afterLoad);

            function afterLoad() {
                var height = $('#dark #light .target img').height();

                $('#dark #light').animate({'height':height},700,afterHeight);
                console.log('working');
            }

            function afterHeight(){
                $('#dark #light .target img').stop(true).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);

            }

            $('#dark').show();

        }

        function light_off() {
            $('#dark #light .target img').stop(true).animate({'opacity':'0'},1000);

            $('#dark').hide();
        }

        $('#gallery .piece').click(light_on);
        $('#dark #light .close').click(light_off);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't load() method registered twice with afterLoad() ?

Comment: Yes I think that's part of the problem - but I honestly don't know which part to get rid of. I've tried both and it doesn't seem to make a difference.